# numbers of people has/have?

Tags: british-english, subject-verb-agreement

Why does "numbers of people" take "has" not "have"?

> Expenditure on direct payments has risen as ***numbers of people***
>   using them **has** increased and now ***equates*** to £1.1 billion or
>   6% of overall gross expenditure for adults.

Source: An overview of the UK domiciliary care sector February 2013 [PDF file](http://www.ukhca.co.uk/pdfs/domiciliarycaresectoroverview.pdf)

> Our freedoms are being forfeited as our numbers grow. Quality of life
>   is reduced as numbers of humans increase.

Source: San Francisco Chronicle, EDITORIAL; Pg. 6; Letters to the editor; via COCA

**Edit:**

Grammar Glitch Central's take on  [“Numbers of participants has…?](http://www.grammarglitchcentral.com/2011/05/numbers-of-participants-has/)

**Edit: more examples**

> Two Medway Grammar Schools, Chatham Boys and Chatham girls have over a
>   hundred spaces between them, **as numbers of** children in Medway **drops**
>   sharply.

Source: [Grammar & Non-selective oversubscription and vacancies, in Kent & Medway secondary schools](http://www.kentadvice.co.uk/peters-blog/news-a-comments/news-archive/item/395-secondary-transfer-in-kent-medway-oversubscription-and-vacancies-grammar-and-non-selective.html)

> In both cases, divergence from the 7:3 ratio will be deemed to be
>   drift, in retrospect at least, if the divergence declines **as numbers
>   of** tosses or generations **increases**.

Source: Darwinian Reductionism: Or, How to Stop Worrying and Love Molecular Biology, Alexander Rosenberg, 2008 via Google Books

Comment: It could be because of the collective noun. This is similar to *"clusters of stars has been discovered recently"*.

Comment: @TRomano Because of that I cited the page. To show that it considers it wrong while the cited sentence from the UK link uses the construction with a singular verb form.

Comment: It is an error in the PDF.

Comment: I wish the person who down voted the question had stated the reason for doing so! I could learn from their feedback or s/he might learn something if they had commented. Just curious!

Comment: Isn't there a difference between American and British English in verb agreement for certain collective nouns though? Not that "numbers of people" is a collective noun, but I vaguely recall that whether the singular or plural tense was used depended on if the group was being referred to as a group or as each member individually.

Comment: I removed my downvote after you edited the question. We were typing at the same time. Better to phrase the question, `Why does this passage treated "numbers" as a singular not a plural?`

Comment: Thank you for the letting me know. I think your reputation level allows you to edit my question so you could have used this feature. And yes I thought I should have been specific as you mentioned. However, it's never been about the points; only the why!

Comment: In `the number of ....` *number* is a collective noun where either a singular or plural verb might be permissible, though I would use a singular. The number has increased. But the plural *numbers* is not a collective noun, IMO.

Comment: Above, treat, not treated. I wish comments could be edited for longer than 5 minutes. Sometimes people get phone calls :-)

Comment: Could "as" have any effect? I am lost in here

Comment: *As* would not have any effect upon the number of *numbers*.

Comment: I'd bet good money that the author would not say "Large numbers of people is attending the protest."

Comment: And it looks like there is an article missing. Shouldn't it be "the numbers of people using them" ? I think this may be a case of poor editing after all. Someone may have substituted the phrase without reviewing the entire sentence.

Comment: Keep in mind *the number of children* and *a number of children* are different grammatically.  "The number of children **has** ..." "A number of children **have** ..."  I have to say that the examples in your post seem ungrammatical to me, and I have no explanation for them.

Comment: Note the use of plural verb form in the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 3rd edition. Also, notice the semi-idiomatic usage of (large) and (small) with (of) in sing the word numbers. Words in Bold in the examples are set by the dictionary ------
*numbers*: a number of a particular description 
 1- **Small** numbers **of** children are educated at home.   
 2- **Large** numbers **of** invitations were sent.

Comment: If we change these to similar-looking phrases that are singular in form, "*A number* of children *are*" and "*A number* of invitations *were*", we find that they still take plural number agreement.  This can be considered a type of **notional agreement**, as the phrase is **notionally plural** despite being singular in form.  This phrase is about **multiple children**.  But "The *number* of children *has*" is different―this phrase is about **a single number** rather than **multiple children**, so the notional override doesn't apply here.  ("Notional" here means "semantic, conceptual".)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a difference here between American and British usage.

In America, we would say "The number of people has increased." (Omitting all the irrelevant parts of the sentence.) Then it makes sense: "number" is the subject of the sentence, and "number" is singular. There may be a million people, but there is only one NUMBER of those people. Thus "the number has increased". A singular subject with a singular verb.

I don't know if the usage in the UK is different, or if this was a mistake in the original document.

Comment: Only very few search results have the singular verb form used. If this is really the case, would the singular form be considered plain wrong or nonstandard?